# Erro de conversão ao tentar inserir no banco com entity e c#

Tags: c#

Esse é o método para inserir:

```
public virtual void Inserir(T item) 
        {
            contexto.Set<T>().Add(item);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Criei um método passando os parâmetros para meu objeto e depois chamar o método inserir, assim(tentei evitar o "linguição", mas não consegui):

```
private void InserirBalanca(int ticket, DateTime dtlancamento, string fornecedor, string motorista, string placa, decimal peso,
                                    decimal umidade, decimal impureza, decimal pesoliq, decimal desconto, decimal valorsec, decimal saca, 
                                    decimal tabela, string pesagem)
        {
            SiloContext contexto = new SiloContext();
            IRepositorio<Balanca> insere = new Repositorio<Balanca>(contexto);

            var balanca = contexto.Balancas;

            foreach(var blc in balanca)
            {
                blc.Ticket = ticket;
                blc.DtLancamento = dtlancamento;
                blc.Fornecedor = fornecedor;
                blc.Motorista = motorista;
                blc.Placa = placa;
                blc.Peso = peso;
                blc.Umidade = umidade;
                blc.Impureza = impureza;
                blc.PesoLiq = pesoliq;
                blc.Desconto = desconto;
                blc.ValorSec = valorsec;
                blc.Saca = saca;
                blc.Tabela = tabela;
                blc.Pesagem = pesagem;
                balanca.Add(blc);
            }

            insere.Inserir(balanca);
        }
```

Nessa linha `insere.Inserir(balanca);`, está dando erro de cast, veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consultei esse erro na net, mas não veio resultado, creio que é por causa do nome Balanca.

Comment: São recebidos dados para inserir uma única balança correto? se sim , qual motivo para realizar um for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cara, o seu `balanca` vem do `contexto.Balancas;` logo, é um `DbSet`. O método `inserir` espera receber um objeto `Balanca`

também não entendi o pq do foreach, mas, de acordo com seu código o que você está querendo fazer deveria ficar +- assim:

```
        foreach(var blc in balanca)
        {
            blc.Ticket = ticket;
            blc.DtLancamento = dtlancamento;
            blc.Fornecedor = fornecedor;
            blc.Motorista = motorista;
            blc.Placa = placa;
            blc.Peso = peso;
            blc.Umidade = umidade;
            blc.Impureza = impureza;
            blc.PesoLiq = pesoliq;
            blc.Desconto = desconto;
            blc.ValorSec = valorsec;
            blc.Saca = saca;
            blc.Tabela = tabela;
            blc.Pesagem = pesagem;
            insere.Inserir(blc);
        }
```

**Edit:**

Conforme eu e Alexandre comentamos, não entendemos o porque do foreach, ou seja, porque você percorre todos os registros armazenados no banco, e sai inserindo todos novamente com os novos valores passados. Você deveria apenas criar um novo objeto `Balanca` e inserir. Ficaria assim:

```
    private void InserirBalanca(int ticket, DateTime dtlancamento, string fornecedor, string motorista, string placa, decimal peso,
                                decimal umidade, decimal impureza, decimal pesoliq, decimal desconto, decimal valorsec, decimal saca, 
                                decimal tabela, string pesagem)
    {
        SiloContext contexto = new SiloContext();
        IRepositorio<Balanca> insere = new Repositorio<Balanca>(contexto);

        var blc = new Balanca();
        blc.Ticket = ticket;
        blc.DtLancamento = dtlancamento;
        blc.Fornecedor = fornecedor;
        blc.Motorista = motorista;
        blc.Placa = placa;
        blc.Peso = peso;
        blc.Umidade = umidade;
        blc.Impureza = impureza;
        blc.PesoLiq = pesoliq;
        blc.Desconto = desconto;
        blc.ValorSec = valorsec;
        blc.Saca = saca;
        blc.Tabela = tabela;
        blc.Pesagem = pesagem;

        insere.Inserir(blc);
    }
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu fiz o foreach, por não saber fazer de outra forma, ou seja, carregar meu objeto com dados e depois persistir. Como eu disse, não consegui evitar o linguição e estou até procurando uma outra forma de fazer, que não seja dessa forma, mas por enquanto vou testando assim. Eu já havia resolvido, mas marquei sua resposta.

Comment: @pnet editei a resposta para explicar a questão do foreach, veja se lhe ajuda.

Comment: Ok, melhorou sim.